# Click edit glyphicon to convert readonly input field to editable

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

Firstly, I am sorry I cannot post any code as I really don't know how to do it. I'll try to explain my design. Say there is a read-only input in a page. Besides that input space, I have an edit glyphicon. I have to click it to make the field editable. When I press Enter, the input field becomes read-only with the value I entered. I have seen this in some forms, but don't know how to do it. Can anyone give any pointers on how to implement this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: See this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help OR just add your code inside `<pre> HERE </pre>` tags

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? [Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ogk49skp/2/)

HTML:

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control disable" disabled="disabled">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default editBtn" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></button>
      </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the JS:

```
$('.editBtn').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        if ($('.disable').attr('disabled')){
            $('.disable').removeAttr('disabled');
        }else{
            $('.disable').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
 });
```